# android preview screen

Tags: android, экран, preview

Сворачиваю приложение. В менеджере свернутых приложений отображается последнее состояние activity перед тем как его свернули.
Как можно изменить фон, который отображается?

```
Разметка:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:text="text"
    android:textColor="#000" />

</LinearLayout>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameID"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000"
    android:visibility="visible"
    />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Код Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    frameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    super.onStop();
}
```

Хотелось бы что бы когда сворачиваешь приложение, был темный фон. 
Пытался, сделать это в onStop. Но система видимо раньше делает скрин экрана.

Answer (score 1):

В методе он onStop меняйте "фон" на тот который хотите, а когда разворачиваете в onResume меняйте обратно(если я правильно понял ваш вопрос).

Comment: Пробовал делать:
@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        super.onStop();
    }
Видимо система делает скрин. раньше
т.к отображается не тот результат

Comment: Возможно, можно как то системно задать?

Comment: @beg_android если бы ты добавил код было бы проще помочь. Не совсем понятно какого конкретно результата ты хочешь достичь.

Comment: добавил код выше

Comment: @beg_android а его вообще видно если не делать GONE в onResume? Просто вы как то страшно намутили.. И LinearLayout i RelativeLayout i FrameLayout..

Comment: FrameLayout изначально виден.
В методе onResume скрывается и соответственно когда срабатывает onStop , должен быть виден.

Comment: @beg_android очень странно... попробуйте програмно таким же образом поменять background у родительского леяута, у меня сохраняются все UI изменения и отображаются в свернутом виде.